# why my cloud function continues to run even though it has finished the task?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

so I try to make thumbnail from an image that has been uploaded to firebase storage. the function can generate the thumbnail correctly. but from the function log, it seems that the function still run repeatedly even though the thumbnail has been generated perfectly.

as you can see from the log below, the function runs from 2:37 to 2:40 over and over again. I need to delete the function from the terminal to stop the function.

[image]
[image]

here is the code I use:

```
export const generateEventThumbnail = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async (object) => {

      const fileBucket = object.bucket; // The Storage bucket that contains the file.
      const filePath = object.name; // File path in the bucket.
      const contentType = object.contentType; // File content type.
      const fileName = path.basename(filePath); // Get the file name.

      console.log(filePath)
      console.log(fileName)

      if (!contentType.startsWith('image/')) {
        console.log('This is not an image.');
        return null;
      }




      try {

        // [START thumbnailGeneration]
        // Download file from bucket.
        const bucket = gcs.bucket(fileBucket);
        const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), fileName);
        const metadata = {contentType: contentType};
        await bucket.file(filePath).download({destination: tempFilePath})
        console.log('Image downloaded locally to', tempFilePath)

        // Generate a thumbnail using ImageMagick.
        await spawn('convert', [tempFilePath, '-thumbnail', '100x100>', tempFilePath])
        console.log('Thumbnail created at', tempFilePath)

        // We add a 'thumb_' prefix to thumbnails file name. That's where we'll upload the thumbnail.
        const thumbFileName = `${fileName}`;
        const thumbFilePath = `eventThumbnail/${thumbFileName}`

        // Uploading the thumbnail.
        await bucket.upload(tempFilePath, {destination: thumbFilePath,metadata: metadata})

        // Once the thumbnail has been uploaded delete the local file to free up disk space.
        fs.unlinkSync(tempFilePath)
        // [END thumbnailGeneration]


        // then save the thumbnail path to the event data in firestore database

        return Promise.resolve(null)



      }
      catch (error) {
          console.log(error)
      }




    });
```

how to stop the function after I successfully generate the thumbnail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're writing a thumbnail back to storage:

```
const thumbFilePath = `eventThumbnail/${thumbFileName}`
await bucket.upload(tempFilePath, {destination: thumbFilePath,metadata: metadata})
```

This triggers your function again, but you're not checking correctly if the new thumbnail should be processed again.

This is the only check you're performing now for early termination:

```
if (!contentType.startsWith('image/')) {
    console.log('This is not an image.');
    return null;
}
```

Which obviously isn't working in your case.  Maybe you should check the path of the newly written files instead of looking at its content type.  Maybe skipping files written to `eventThumbnail` would work for your case.